# Kafka Consumer get key value pair

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently working with Kafka and Flink, I have kafka running in my local PC and I created a topic that is being consumed.

Desktop\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 -topic test

but it is just retrieving the message, [image]

is there a way to get futher details about the message ? lets say time? key? I checked kafka documentation but I didn't find something about this topic

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Using out of the box console consumer (I am using Kafka 0.9.0.1) you can only print the key and the value of messages using different formats. To print the key, set the property `print.key=true`.

There is another property `key.separator` that by default is "\t" (a tab) that you can also change to anything you want.

To set these properties you can create a config file and use `--consumer.config <config file>` or pass the properties using `--property key=value`.

You can also implement your own formatter and use it with `--formatter` option but you will still have just the key and value because that is what the *MessageFormatter* trait provides (see writeTo below).

```
trait MessageFormatter {
    def writeTo(key: Array[Byte], value: Array[Byte], output: PrintStream)

    def init(props: Properties) {}

    def close() {}
}
```

For example:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka-1:9092 --topic topic1 --property print.key=true --property key.separator="-" --from-beginning
key-p1
key-p2
key-p3
null-4
null-8
null-0
```

Comment: I don't want to open a new question, that being  said I think Kafka should provide a way to specify  the key from the producer for each message or at least for each topic. Do you know what can I use ?

Comment: $ ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka-1:9092 --topic topic1 --property parse.key=true --property key.separator="-"
thekey-thevalue

Comment: Solved the problem for me..

Answer (score 19):

Use below command:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic_name \ 
      --from-beginning --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter \
      --property print.key=true --property print.value=true \
      --property key.deserialzer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer \
      --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
```

Comment: note for windows Users  => for cmd replace \ with ^